# nodejs socket.io callbacks logic

Tags: node.js, callback, socket.io

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){  
    socket.on('customevent', function(){...})   
...})
```

`io.sockets.on` simplified logic: each socket will respond to an event (`'connection'` by default);
`socket.on` simplified logic: each socket will respond to an event only if connection is established (only when `'connection'` event is received);

So, what is the logic here? Is `io.sockets.on` function used only for establishing connection like a simple callback?
I see that both functions stand for 'each socket responds' and there is no need in `socket.on` because `io.sockets.on` will respond to all events as well as `socket.on`'s given socket.

Could someone explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible for different socket connections to handle different events differently, depending on their nature. `io.sockets.on(...)` specifies common behavior for all socket connections (i.e. behavior that doesn't depend on the identity of the connection); `socket.on(...)` (where `socket` represents a particular connection) specifies behavior specific to that connection.